# Remove print of chunk labels and progress bar in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am creating an Rmarkdown and have lots of useful error messages, like "I am here" in the below example. However it is difficult to find the useful error message with the label output. How do you switch the label print off but keep the messages?

````
---
title: "label_example"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12
                      , fig.height=5.5
                      , echo=FALSE
                      , warning=FALSE
                      , message=FALSE
                      , results='asis')
```

## R Markdown


```{r cars}
message("I am Here")
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

|.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

|...................                                              |  29%
label: setup (with options)

processing file: label_example.Rmd
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

|............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

|.....................................                            |  57%
label: cars
  |..............................................                   |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

|........................................................         |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

|.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code

/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS label_example.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output label_example.pdf --template/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
I am Here
output file: label_example.knit.md